# content-type related nginx expires header

Tags: nginx, expires-header

Is it possible to set a content-type dependent expires header in nginx? I'm quite new to nginx and tried the following:

```
    location ~ /files\.php$ {
    ...
            if ($content_type = "text/css") {
                    add_header X-TEST1 123;
                    expires 7d;
            }
            if ($content_type = "image/png") {
                    add_header X-TEST2 123;
                    expires 30d;
            }
            if ($content_type = "application/javascript") {
                    add_header X-TEST3 123;
                    expires 1d;
            }
            #testing
            if ($content_type != "text/css") {
                    add_header X-TEST4 abc;
            }
            #testing
            if ($content_type = text/css) {
                    add_header X-TEST5 123;
            }
    }
```

But the only header added is "X-TEST4" on all requests.
I know about the other solution using file extension:

```
location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jp?g|png)\?[0-9]+$
```

But it's not applicable for my application.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code should be in `location / { }` instead of `location ~ /files\.php$ { }`...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$content_type ~= application/javascript
```

Also, make sure to read this:
http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

Comment: Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unexpected "~=" in condition in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/a.localhost:49

Answer (score 0):

**If you have the lua module installed you could do something similar like this:**

```
server {

    location / {...}

    header_filter_by_lua_block {

            local cct = {}  -- # cached content types

            cct["text/css"] = true
            cct["application/javascript"] = true
            cct["application/x-javascript"] = true
            cct["text/javascript"] = true
            cct["image/jpeg"] = true
            cct["image/png"] = true
            cct["application/vnd.ms-fontobject"] = true
            cct["application/font-woff"] = true
            cct["application/x-font-truetype"] = true
            cct["image/svg+xml"] = true
            cct["application/x-font-opentype"] = true

            if cct[ngx.header.content_type] ~= nil and ngx.header["expires"] == nil then
                    local now = os.time()
                    local expires = os.date("%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%I:%S GMT", now+604800) -- # one week in seconds

                    ngx.header["expires"] = expires
            end
    }
}
```

Responses with the specified content-type will now get an expires-header.
When the response already has an expires-header the lua block will not touch the header.

Comment: There should %a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S but not GMT %a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%I:%S GMT. %I -stands for number of hours not minutes